# Why is the first homology group of the torus is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, direct-sum, simplicial-complex

For the torus below:

[image]

I would like to compute $H_1^\Delta(T)$. Here is how I did:

We have $C_1=\Delta_1(T)=\mathbb{Z}$ and $C_2=\Delta_2(T)=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ am I right? $C_i=\Delta_i(T)$ is always a free abelian group isn't it?

$H_1^\Delta(T)=\frac{\ker\partial_1}{\text{im }\partial_2}=\frac{\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}}{\mathbb{Z}}=\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, where $*$ denotes the free product.

But the working solution given in Hatcher's page 106 is:

[image]

My question is:

1. Is my working correct? And why is the first simplicial homology group of the torus is $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?
2. What is the difference between $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$?

I am really confused. I appreciate any helps and explanation. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by $*$? Also, $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\cong \mathbb Z\oplus\mathbb Z$.

Comment: If $*$ is the free product, then how is $\Delta_2(T)=\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z*\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Because each $C_i=\Delta_i(T)$ is a free abelian group right? (written on Hatcher's page 99)

Comment: The free product is not the same as the free abelian product. If $A$ and $B$ are abelian groups, then $A*B$ is not an abelian group.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So that means $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ is the free abelian product?

Comment: @user71346 Yes, that's correct (although I've never heard it called that . . .).

Comment: Yes, $\oplus$ can be defined as an "abelian" version of the free product, though it usually isn't called that.

Comment: I've never heard it called that, but it is related to the free product in a way that is deep.

Comment: Umm, I sort of get it but the elements of a free product are words right? But the elements of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ are not words? @EricWofsey

Comment: How do you define the free product? Have you seen a definition of $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews elements of free product are reduced words under the operation of concatenation followed by reduction. I have also seen the definition of direct sum which is more or less like the cartesian product.

Comment: Yes, the only part of cartesian sum that is different is the case of an infinite cartesian sum. @user71346

Comment: If you define the free product using words, then it's not particularly related to the direct sum.  But there is a different definition using a universal property, and if you take that definition and replace "group" with "abelian group" everywhere you get a definition of direct sums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation $*$ denotes the *free product* of groups, which notably is an operation on groups, not just abelian groups.  So $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ is the free (nonabelian) group on two generators, not the free *abelian* group on two generators.

There is no difference between $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$: they mean the exact same thing (or in some contexts, their definitions may be different but you can prove they are canonically isomorphic).

(There is, however, a difference when talking about infinite products versus infinite direct sums: $\prod_{i\in I} A_i$ denotes the set of all tuples indexed by the set $I$ where the $i$th coordinate is in $A_i$ for all $i$, while $\bigoplus_{i\in I}A_i$ denotes the subgroup of $\prod_{i\in I}A_i$ consisting of elements that are $0$ on all but finitely many coordinates.)

Comment: One doubt, why $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ must be the free nonabelian and cannot be free abelian?

Comment: Take any nonabelian group $G$ with two elements $a,b\in G$ that do not commute.  By definition of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, there is a homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}\to G$ sending the generators of $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ to $a$ and $b$.  So the generators cannot commute.